# How to set page expire in php if the user inactive for 10 mintues?

Tags: php

I am new to this php I doing a small project I want to code page to expire if the user is inactive for than 5 minutes and it should not go to next page.

I have seen some codes but they are not working on exactly what I want.

\thanks in advance

Comment: 5 minutes or 10 minutes?

Comment: **I have seen some codes but they are not working on exactly what I want.** So please tell us what you have done so far and where are the problems with the "codes" that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php session to detect the users inactive time. When page loads first time then store the current time in one session variable, then use that session value to get the users inactive time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a small issue , when you are creating session don't put custom time , the default time of session is normally 5 - 6 minutes , keep it as it is . Now create a PHP file where you need to add the following code :-

```
if (!isset ($_SESSION['user']) || $_SESSION['user'] == ''){
    echo "<script>alert ('Sorry, you are already logged out, please login again to continue ...') ; </script>" ;
    echo "<script> setTimeout(function(){window.location = 'index.php' ;}, 2000) ; </script>" ;
}
```

Use the proper session variable name in your project . The session will automatically logged out a user .